# React JS CSS could not proxy error on multiple tree url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am creating some dynamic URL in ReactJs and some CSS and JS are being imported in public/index.html.
My site loads completely well if the URL is like 'http://localhost:3000/property' but if the URL is something like this 'http://localhost:3000/property/abc' I get a console error.
Error:

```
Proxy error: Could not proxy request /property/js/script.js from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:3000/.
[1] See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNRESET).
```

PS: React is adding /property to all imported CSS and JS.

[image]